# Passing env/params values to the Shell Service plugin of Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ssh

Shell Service of Jenkins plugin is like in the picture that is below. I need to pass params/env variable to it but couldn't make it.
Is there any way to pass values into "Execute shell script on remote host using ssh"?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this plugin works as a usual ssh command, you can escape $DOCKER_REGISTRY quotes

```
ssh jenkins@192.168.13.156:22  "echo \"$DOCKER_REGISTRY\""
```

IMHO: Get rid of the ssh plugins in Jenkins, just use shell, is way more flexible.

Comment: I'm receiving `Permission denied, please try again.` Why Jenkins is passing cred info automatically?

Comment: Did you copy the ssh keys? On the server-side, check if Jenkins user has the proper permissions.

Comment: Jenkins has but it didn't pass in shell. Would you please reply with username and pass version of this?